# Fixed Point queries-1

Tags: fixed-point

I would really appreciate if I can get answers to following Fixed point queries(part-1):

**Converting a real number x to fixed point fraction X(m,n)**

1. [1] says:
   m = ceil(log2(max[abs(xmin,xmax)+1])) { assuming signed x>1) or
   m = floor(log2(max[abs(xmin,xmax)+2])) { assuming signed x<1}            (1.1)
   and xmin,xmax define the known range of x. if WL desired is known = m+ n , then, n= WL - m.

Q1) Can this be used blindly? What if we don't know the expected range of x?

2. [2] defines:  if floating x had "d" fractional digits,
   compute ceil(3.3 * d).                   (1.2)
   Q2)  Is Fraction Length n = ceil(3.3 * d)  or n+1  = ceil(3.3 * d)
   Q3) What about floor(3.3*f) or any other scheme?
   Q4) Where would I use equation 1.1 over 1.2 and vice versa?
   Suppose we have computed Fraction  length n by any of the above methods.
   Now, The integer representation and the quantized value is computed as:
   X= round/floor/fix(x*(2^n)); xq(Quantized value) =  X/(2^n);
   (Q5) Does choosing round/floor/fix here determine the type of quantizer? If yes,
      which option gives a rounding quantizer and which one does a truncation quantizer?

Reference:

1.http://www.superkits.net/whitepapers/Fixed%20Point%20Representation%20&%20Fractional%20Math.pdf( equation 9 and Equation 12)
 2.  DSP, a practical approach:Efeachor (page 809-810,second edition)

Thank You so much
sedy

Comment: if you have no idea of the expected range of $x$, you will have a problem using fixed point.  assuming the range of $x$ is not astronomical, single-precision floating point is not too bad, but you **have** to have some idea of the range of values of your numbers if you ever hope to use fixed-point representation of those numbers efficaciously.

Comment: i'm pretty skeptical about any of those "3.3" factors.  they seem like a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants).  it has nothing to do with the necessary number of **bits**, but the source says "digits" (as if that is a useful measure and that ($\log_2(10)$) is where that 3.3 factor comes from.  it's still pretty useless.

Comment: $\operatorname{floor}(x)$ always rounds down to the nearest integer value, $\operatorname{round}(x)$ always rounds up or down to the nearest integer and is usually equivalent to $\operatorname{floor}(x+0.5)$ (there **is** an issue of "convergent rounding" where it rounds $xxx.5$ to the nearest **even** integer, not all rounding functions do that).  $\operatorname{fix}(x)$ always rounds toward 0.  positive $x$ rounds down, negative $x$ rounds up.

Comment: pleeze try using $\LaTeX$ markup with your questions.  costs you a little more time, but saves the rest of us collectively a lot more time.  and there are more of us than you.

Comment: Q5: 'fix' gives a truncation quantizer, and 'round' obviously gives a rounding quantizer.

Comment: Q5: For two's complement fixed-point representation 'floor' would be the truncation quantizer. (Matt L. is correct for sign-magnitude representation.) As a side note: 'fix' is sometimes referred to as 'magnitude truncation' (independent of representation).

Comment: Thanks Guys.How Do i close this/accept solution?